# Illegal use of type in template

Tags: c++, templates, template-function

I'm new to templates. I can't figure out what am i doing wrong:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void inc(T* data)
{
    (*T)++;
}

int main()
{
    char x = 'x';
    int b = 1602;

    inc<char>(&x);
    inc<int>(&b);
    cout << x << ", " << b << endl;

    int a = 0;
    cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling in VS2013 i got an error:
Error   1   error C2275: 'T' : illegal use of this type as an expression

Comment: `*T` attempts to dereference a type, hence the error.

Comment: Replace `(*T)++` with `(*data)++`.

Comment: wow, i'm dumb as hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should:

```
template <typename T>
void inc(T* data)
{
    (*data)++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`*T` tries to dereferece the `data_type` that is why you are getting error.

Please replace the line number 8 of given code snippet with

```
(*data)++;
```